# Breaking line in \email command

Tags: line-breaking, email

I'm trying to break a line in the \email command because there are a lot of authors on the work that I'm doing and, for some reason, I cannot.
Already tried to use \\, \hfill \break and \newline but none of these commands seem to work. Here's some code about the case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sbc-template}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  

     
\sloppy

\title{Blockchain - Uma técnologia disruptiva}

\author{Sandro G. B. Azevedo\inst{1}, João R. M. Gubolin\inst{1}, Gabriel F. L. Fichera\inst{1},\\ William W. C. Correia\inst{1},Matheus S. Marsicano\inst{1}}


\address{Universidade Estadual Paulista "Júlio de Mesquita Filho" -- 
  (UNESP)\\
  São José do Rio  Preto -- SP -- Brazil
  \email{sandro.azevedo@unesp.br, joao.gubolin@unesp.br, gabriel.fichera@unesp.br,(HERE IS THE PLACE I WANT TO BREAK A LINE) william.colla@unesp.br,ms.marsicano@unesp.br}
}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

In order to work, you must have the file sbc-template.sty in your overleaf project.

It can be easily found on

> https://github.com/uefs/sbc-template-latex/blob/master/sbc-template.sty

Answer (score 2):

Update `\email` to handle line breaks by setting it inside a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sbc-template}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\email}[1]{\\\mbox{}\\[-6pt]\footnotesize\ttfamily\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}#1\end{tabular}}
     
\title{Blockchain - Uma técnologia disruptiva}

\author{Sandro GB Azevedo\inst{1}, João RM Gubolin\inst{1}, Gabriel FL Fichera\inst{1},\\ William WC Correia\inst{1}, Matheus S Marsicano\inst{1}}


\address{Universidade Estadual Paulista ``Júlio de Mesquita Filho'' -- 
  (UNESP)\\
  São José do Rio Preto -- SP -- Brazil
  \email{sandro.azevedo@unesp.br, joao.gubolin@unesp.br, gabriel.fichera@unesp.br,\\ william.colla@unesp.br,ms.marsicano@unesp.br}
}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```